# nopCommerce 3.0 How to get user selected store and category on product detail page?

Tags: nopcommerce

I want to show user selected store and category on product detail page like this 
**Store Name Category Name > Product Name**.
How can I get user selected store and category from Product detail page. I use nopCommerce 3.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the store name, you can use the store context object:

```
_storeContext.CurrentStore
```

But for the category, are you aware that a product can belong to multiple categories in nopCommerce? This is stored in the `ProductCategories` collection of the `Product` entity.

Comment: I want to get user selected category value on product detail page if user selected current product from one of category.It can be possible?

Comment: I think this may be little complicated. First, you need to handle the common case where a user goes directly to a product details page, from a Google search result for instance. Second, you need to identify the level of persistence you want to achieve. Do you want to save the last visited category in the database? Or in a cookie? Or do you want to save the list of all visited categories in a stack? Or may be you just need to get the last visited category from the URL referrer HTTP header.

Comment: Just remembered that nopCommerce saves the Last Visited Page of the current user. You can retrieve it using `MyCurrentCustomerObject.GetAttribute<string>(SystemCustomerAttributeNames.LastVisitedPage);`, but you'll have to use the Url Record Service to find out if this last visited page is for a category and accordingly load the category object. NopCommerce uses the URL Record Service to map SEO-Friendly URLs back to entities.

Comment: How to use URL Record Service?Can I get sample?

Comment: Just search the code for _urlRecordService. This is always the name of any URL Record Service instance. This the service layer class that manages URL records. I am sure you will find it straightforward once you look it up in the code.

Answer (score 0):

I have a problem with

```
_storeContext.CurrentStore
```

This everytime gives me wrong store information and the reason is described here

[plugin-get-current-storeid-multi-store](http://www.nopcommerce.com/boards/t/35297/plugin-get-current-storeid-multi-store.aspx)

So i have used the below code which i got from looking NivoSlider Plugin .

> var storeScope = this.GetActiveStoreScopeConfiguration(_storeService,
>   _workContext);

`_storeService` is type of `IStoreService`

`_workContext` is type of `IWorkContext`

Use it via dependency injection from constructor.